# Using VBA - Hyperlink where hyperlink is variable (based on Address & Match formula)

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, macros, vlookup

I'm hoping someone can help me, as I'm well and truly stuck.

I am trying to write a Macro which would follow a hyperlink to a cell in another spreadsheet.  The reason I've chosen to use a hyperlink is that I need the cell reference to be variable.

The formula I've written is as follows:

`=HYPERLINK("#'Label Editor'!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(A1,'Label Editor'!$B$1:$B$1001,0),3),"Go to label")`

The formula works fine - however the problem is when I attempt to record a macro.  Instead of following the hyperlink, it records a fixed cell reference as below:

```
Sub Test1()
'
' Test1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+q
'
    Range("G1:I1").Select
    **Application.Goto Reference:="'Label Editor'!R125C3"**
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("5x13").Select
    Range("A2:A22").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I've tried to find a way to integrate the hyperlink within the macro, but so far to no avail.  I've tried replacing it with a Lookup formula as follows:

```
**Application.Goto Reference:=Application.VLookup([A1], [Label Editor], [$b$1:c$1000], 2, False)**
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("5x13").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I2:I254,G2:G254,E2:E254,C2:C254,A2:A254").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

However this comes up with: Run-time error '1004':

I'm now completely stuck - can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Follow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839219.aspx) method of the [Hyperlinks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835563.aspx) object.

**Example**

```
ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow
```

Comment: Thanks @destination-data.  I've amended the macro to include        **Range("g1:i1").Select**
    **ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow**
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("5x13").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I2:I254,G2:G254,E2:E254,C2:C254,A2:A254").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False

This now comes up with **Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range**

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow

Comment: That means the active cell doesn't contain a hyperlink.  If your hyperlink was in G1 you could change the code to: `Range("G1").Hyperlinks(1).Follow`.

Comment: I've tried that, however it's still not working.  Could it be to do with the formula in the cell?  I've simplified the formula but wonder if requiring the additional formulas "Address" & "Match" is making a difference?  Formula is: =HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(MATCH('5x13'!A1,$B$1:$B$1001,0),3),"GO")